# does a child under 2 need a passport for a Mexican domestic flight?

Tags: air-travel, mexico

My husband, 1.6 year old and myself will be crossing the U.S border into Tijuana this friday. We plan on flying from Tijuana to Chihuahua and back. Does my child under 2 years old need a passport to be able to fly from Tijuana to Chihuahua when both places are in Mexico? Keep in mind I have crossed the border multiple times with my child with just a birth certificate.

Comment: Typically domestic flights don't require passports

Comment: Not necessarily a passport, but an official ID